# Get SDL TTF string width from another thread

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, sdl, truetype

I'm writing a multithreaded C++ library that uses SDL, and I can't call TTF_SizeText while calling any other SDL method. All other SDL methods are either graphics functions (only on one thread) or basic window functions (not used often and locked).

- I was going to cache the font glyphs and the kerning between each
  letter but neither TTF_GetFontKerningSize or
  TTF_GetFontKerningSizeGlyphs work.
- I believe the only reason they can't run is because of basic SDL
  functions like SDL_strlen. I attempted to rewrite the method
  TTF_SizeText (Can be viewed here:
  https://github.com/limbahq/example-neverball/blob/master/SDL2-full/SDL2-ttf/SDL_ttf.c)
  but I have mostly developed in Java and I'm not sure if it's even
  possible.
- Another option might be to only load string widths on the
  graphics thread but I have to load a lot of various strings and it
  would be messy to code
- One last idea I had was loading freetype seperately and using that,
  but it could be messy as well.

Any insight into my problem is appreciated

Comment: What does "can't call" mean here? What 'other functions' are you talking about, exactly? Strlen have to be thread-safe, it makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: "can't call" as in the program crashes when I do. Like I said, that was just an idea and was not specifically talking about strlen.